# setting document.referrer on Landing page using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Can you please guide me in setting up a Custom dimension which stores document.referrer only on the entry page of the website. So, this value remains same throughout the whole session.
At the moment problem for me is Document.referrer is being updated with the new value of the previous page.
Any help with clear explanation is highly appreciated.

cheers!

Comment: If you are referring to the native JS property, you cannot write that. However Google Analytics stores the referrer only when it is different from the pages hostname, so as far as tracking is concerned this is already covered. Perhaps you can clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

[document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) is read only. You shouldn't be trying to overwrite it with the value from the first request. Browsers will handle this unexpected action differently.

By the sounds of it, you want to use a session cookie or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) to persist the first page url of the session. GTM can access both. sessionStorage or localStorage is preferred as it does not require sending any additional info with every request like with cookies.

Have a read of this one: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/two-ways-to-persist-data-via-google-tag-manager/

To add as a custom dimension to GA, you'd want to create a new Variable of type Custom Javascript, which contains a function that reads the value from your persistent storage, then add the Variable to your GA tag.

Read more about custom dimensions here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6164990?hl=en